# iPad navigate full-size page divs using swipe gestures

Tags: ipad, jquery-ui, web-applications

I'm building an iPad magazine for a University project in the form of a web site to demonstrate some of the functionality of my proposed design (the real-life app would of course be native iOS)

I have looked at some frameworks like Sencha which seems overkill for what I want and seems to want to do everything inside JavaScript instead of keeping it to HTML/CSS and then adding the interactions on top. I have also looked at jQuery UI iPad which seems the most promising but I could do with some help getting it to work. Here is a demo of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/blackdynamo/yxhzU/

Here is a sample page for my pages: http://driz.co.uk/ipad/

What I need help with is getting the DIVS to sit next to each other in rows and then add the interaction whereby as a user swipes left, right and up and down it will jump between the different DIVS as though they are pages/sections of a magazine.

**Here is a image that shows how the DIVS would ideally be arranged, so a user could move between the sections going left and right and then scroll inside that section by scrolling up and down. http://driz.co.uk/ipad/plan.png**

Can anyone help me get this working? THANKS LOADS!

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
  /* For general iPad layouts */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
  /* For portrait layouts only */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
  /* For landscape layouts only */
}
```

I am not entirely sure with the divs, sorry. Hope this helps.

Comment: I already have the CSS. The issue is with adding the javascript interactions and getting the divs to sit in a grid format of my choosing.